# How to include multiple COUNT per day in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

Trying to grab a count for 2-3 types of entry determined by column name 'adsource' value of the last 8 days. So far I've been able to grab one type only and add to results. Database MySql.

**Results i'm getting now (only one type):**

```
days_ago     monthday        type1
---------------------------------
1            2016-05-11      2
2            2016-05-10      34
3            2016-05-09      11
4            2016-05-08      1
5            2016-05-07      0
6            2016-05-06      16
7            2016-05-05      42
8            2016-05-04      76
```

**Result I'm after -> 2-3 types(adsource column):**

```
monthday        type1        type2
-----------------------------------------
2016-05-11      1            2
2016-05-10      6            0
2016-05-09      6            6
2016-05-08      1            65
2016-05-07      4            23
2016-05-06      1            12
2016-05-05      3            9
2016-05-04      6            11
```

I don't need the first column days_ago, not sure how to remove it from display. I need to be able to display on results:

```
adsource = 9 as type1
adsource = 12 as type2
adsource = 3 as type3
```

**This is the query I'm using:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), edate) AS days_ago, DATE(edate) AS monthday, 
COUNT(DISTINCT entries.email) AS type1
FROM entries
WHERE iplocation = 'mx' AND adsource = 9
GROUP BY DATE(edate)) AS temp
WHERE days_ago <= 8
GROUP BY monthday
ORDER BY monthday DESC
```

Thank you for any input you might have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), edate) AS days_ago, DATE(edate) AS monthday, 
COUNT(DISTINCT (case when adsource=9 then entries.email end)) AS type1,
COUNT(DISTINCT (case when adsource=12 then entries.email end)) AS type2,
COUNT(DISTINCT (case when adsource=3 then entries.email end)) AS type3
FROM entries
WHERE iplocation = 'mx'
GROUP BY DATE(edate)) AS temp
WHERE days_ago <= 8
GROUP BY monthday
ORDER BY monthday DESC
```

Comment: This is awesome!! Works like a charm and exactly what I needed. Thank you much. I gotta get down and continue reading my sql booklet ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whats the second column?  Just add it to query:

```
SELECT  DATE(edate) AS monthday, COUNT(DISTINCT entries.email) AS type1, COUNT(DISTINCT entries.type2) AS type2
FROM entries
WHERE iplocation = 'mx' AND adsource = 9 AND DATEDIFF(DATE(edate), now())     BETWEEN 0 and 7
GROUP BY DATE(edate)) AS temp
```

Comment: there's no second column to select. the counts go towards adsource value. for example, my query counts adsource 9 as type1. need to add more adsources. does this make sense?

Comment: instead of including adsource to the `where` add it to the `group by` then and you'll just have date, adsource, count as rows and then you can parse it separately.  How many different adsources are there?

Comment: there's about 10 adsource, but really need around 2-3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which database you're using but this should do the trick in any database.

```sql
SELECT A.monthday, A.type1, B.type2 FROM
  (SELECT DATE(edate) as monthday, COUNT(type1) AS type1
    FROM entries 
    WHERE iplocation = 'mx' AND adsource = 9 AND DATEDIFF(DATE(edate), now()) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
    GROUP BY DATE(edate)) AS A
  (SELECT DATE(edate) as monthday, COUNT(type2) AS type2
    FROM entries
    WHERE iplocation = 'mx' AND adsource = 12 AND DATEDIFF(DATE(edate), now()) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
    GROUP BY DATE(edate)) AS B
WHERE A.monthday = B.monthday
```

This will allow you to use multiple different conditions to counting too.